# Prove that $\prod_1^{\infty}(1-a_i) > 0$ iff $\sum_1^{\infty}{a_i} < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

> > Suppose $\{a_i\}_1^{\infty} \subset (0,1)$
> >     
> > a) $\prod_1^{\infty}(1-a_i) > 0$ iff $\sum_1^{\infty}{a_i} < \infty$
> >     
> > b) Given $\beta \in (0,1)$, exhibit a sequence $\{a_i\}$ such that $\prod_1^{\infty}(1-a_i) = \beta$

This is not my homework, but I'm learning measure theory from Real Analysis of Folland, and I get stuck on this problem. My idea is to prove that $\sum_1^{\infty}{\ln(1-a_i)} > -\infty$ (for sure this sum is smaller than 0). At the first glance, I try to prove that $\ln(1-x) + x > 0$, but finally, the inequality should be reversed. Using maclaurine expansion, I can expand:
$$\ln(1-x) = -(x + x^2/2 + x^3/3 +...)$$

So seem like I can't find a function $f(x)$ such that $\ln(1-x) +f(x) > 0$. Can anyone give me some hint to solve this? For the second problem, I got no idea. Thanks so much. I really appreciate!

Comment: What do you mean by $> -\infty$?

Comment: You need to edit the title.

Comment: @Gary: I'm not sure about the way to write it right. What I mean is to prove that that sum is finite.

Comment: For the forward direction, suppose $\sum_1^{\infty} a_i = \infty$. Using the fact that $1-a_i \leq e^{-a_i}$, we see that $\prod_1^n (1-a_i) \leq \prod_1^n e^{-a_i}=e^{\sum_1^n a_i}$. The latter converges to zero since $\sum a_i = \infty$.

Comment: Hint: Express the summation: $\sum_1^{\infty}{1/(1 - a_i)}$ in terms of $\prod_1^{\infty}(1-a_i)$ that would appear in the denominator of that sum.

Comment: @leducquang: Maybe write $<< 0 $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you use $\ln(1-x)<-x$, then you can show that $%
%TCIMACRO{\dprod }%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\prod}
%EndExpansion
\left(  1-a_{i}\right)  >0\rightarrow%
%TCIMACRO{\dsum }%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum}
%EndExpansion
\ln\left(  1-a_{i}\right)  >-\infty\rightarrow%
%TCIMACRO{\dsum }%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum}
%EndExpansion
-a_{i}>-\infty\rightarrow%
%TCIMACRO{\dsum }%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum}
%EndExpansion
a_{i}<\infty.$

Now, if $%
%TCIMACRO{\dsum }%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum}
%EndExpansion
a_{i}<\infty$, then $a_{i}\rightarrow0$. Since $\frac{\ln\left(  1-x\right)
}{x}\rightarrow-1$ as $x\rightarrow0$, we have for $i$ big enough (means
$a_{i}$ small enough): $\ln\left(  1-a_{i}\right)  >-2a_{i}\rightarrow%
%TCIMACRO{\dsum }%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum}
%EndExpansion
\ln\left(  1-a_{i}\right)  >-2%
%TCIMACRO{\dsum }%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum}
%EndExpansion
a_{i}>-\infty$.

For b) if you want $%
%TCIMACRO{\dprod }%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\prod}
%EndExpansion
\left(  1-a_{i}\right)  =\beta\rightarrow$ $%
%TCIMACRO{\dsum }%
%BeginExpansion
{\displaystyle\sum}
%EndExpansion
\ln\left(  1-a_{i}\right)  =\ln\beta$ then you can use the Taylor expansion to
expand $\ln\beta$ and then choosing $a_{i}$ accordingly.